# sql query: list every song belonging to a particular artist, even though there is no direct foreign key reference between them

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables

- artist (artistID, ...)
- album (albumID, artistID, ...)
- song (songID, ...)
- albumsongs (songID, albumID)

and the table that joins the many to many between album and songs - albumsongs

Basically in my albumsongs table I have a song ID, and an album ID.

In the album table I have an artistID.

I want to list every song belonging to a particular artist, even though there is no direct foreign key reference between them. The only real link from artist to song is through album. Is that possible with some sort of advanced query magic?

Comment: Does song or album refer to artist?

Comment: @n8wrl The album table has an artistID, I mentioned that in the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a simple a multi-table join:

```
select artist.name, album.title, song.title
from artist
     inner join album on album.artistid = artist.artistid
     inner join albumsongs on albumsongs.albumid = album.albumid
     inner join songs on songs.songid = albumsongs.songid
where artist.name = 'Pere Ubu'
```

Comment: Add the Where statement to check against the desired artist.

Comment: The OP mentioned _list every song belonging to a particular artist_, so that would lack a `where artist.id = ...`; but besides that tiny detail, here is a +1 for you for getting the multiple join right ;)

Comment: Added a WHERE clause as requested.  It's true I overlooked this, but it seemed the point of the question was how to do the join.  Presumably the fact that the OP accepted the answer meant that it was useful.

Comment: Not looking for useful answers.
Looking for useful, complete, and correct answers. You have an opportunity to correct your answer. Down-voting encourages answers to be edited by the poster to be more thorough following advice given. My comment was helpful for you to resolve the issue, correct? This is the way downvoting is supposed to be used.

Comment: Remember, I'm encouraged to restore your points whenever you correct the answer as well, because I'm penalized for down-voting. I'm glad to have the rep back.

Comment: @Xaadw:  I did add a `WHERE` clause already.  Not sure what else you're looking for.  Also not sure why you think I would be so concerned about your one downvote.  Although I like getting reputation points, my primary concern is whether I can provide an answer that helps the questioner.  And again, apparently it did.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct sng.*
from song sng
inner join albumsongs a_s on a_s.song_id = sng.id
inner join album alb on alb.id = a_s.album_id
inner join artist art on art.id = alb.artist_id
where art.name like '%NAME_CRITERIA_HERE%'
```

or

```
select * from song where id in (
    select a_s.song_id
    from albumsongs a_s
    inner join album alb on alb.id = a_s.album_id
    inner join artist art on art.id = alb.artist_id
    where art.name like '%NAME_CRITERIA_HERE%'
)
```